# Login google by RoboVM/RoboPod

Tags: ios, libgdx, google-signin, robovm, mobivm

Anyone here has used roboPod of roboVM for google sign in.i'm appreciate if you concern my post and answer to me. I don't know how to using this library and i've ever knew programming ios

https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-signin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RoboPods](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-signin) for Google SignIn by [MobiVM](https://github.com/MobiVM)'s RoboVM Fork

1. Follow install [instruction](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-signin/ios)
2. Get an `OAuth client ID` & `URL scheme` for your project from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)
3. Add your `URL scheme` inside `info.plist.xml`

   ```
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
       <string>Editor</string>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.1234567890-qweasdzxcqweasdzxc321456</string>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
          <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.1234567890-qweasdzxcqweasdzxc321456</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
           <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
           <string>Editor</string>
           <key>${bundle.id}</key>
           <string>${bundle.id}</string>
           <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
           <array>
               <string>${bundle.id}</string>
           </array>
   </dict>
   </array>
   ```
4. Inside iOS module

   ```
   GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setUiDelegate(new GIDSignInUIDelegateAdapter() {
           private UIViewController libgdxViewController;

           @Override
           public void willDispatch(GIDSignIn signIn, NSError error) {

           }

           @Override
           public void presentViewController(GIDSignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController) {

               libgdxViewController =  UIApplication.getSharedApplication().getKeyWindow().getRootViewController();
               libgdxViewController.presentViewController(viewController, true, null);
               UIApplication.getSharedApplication().getKeyWindow().setRootViewController(viewController);
           }

           @Override
           public void dismissViewController(GIDSignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController) {
               viewController.dismissViewController(true, null);
           }
       });
   ```

   Set Sign-In callback :

   ```
   GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setDelegate(GIDSignInDelegate v);
   ```

   SignIn

   ```
   GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setClientID(OAUTHCLIENTID); // set OAuth client ID
   GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().signIn();
   ```

   Override `openURL` method inside `IOSLauncher` class:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean openURL(UIApplication application, NSURL url, String sourceApplication, NSObject annotation) {
        boolean canRespond = GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication, (NSPropertyList)annotation);
        if (canRespond) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
   }
   ```

Use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to access platform specific APIs.

**EDIT** *Test Code:*

Inside core module :

1. `SignInServiceApi.java`

   ```
   public interface SignInServiceApi {
       void signIn();
       void signOut();
   }
   ```
2. `MyGDXTest.java`

   ```
   public class MyGDXTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

      private SignInServiceApi signInServiceApi;

       private Stage stage;
       private Label name;
       private Label emailId;
       private Skin skin;

       public Main(SignInServiceApi signInServiceApi){
           this.signInServiceApi=signInServiceApi;
       }

       @Override
       public void create () {

          stage=new Stage(new StretchViewport(400f,640f));
          skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));

          Table root = new Table();
          root.setFillParent(true);
          stage.addActor(root);

          root.defaults().pad(10f);

          name=new Label("Name :", skin);
          emailId=new Label("Email :", skin);

          TextButton signIn=new TextButton("Sign In", skin);
          signIn.addListener(new ClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               signInServiceApi.signIn();
               super.clicked(event, x, y);
           }
         });

          TextButton disconnect=new TextButton("Sign Out", skin);
       disconnect.addListener(new ClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               signInServiceApi.signOut();
               super.clicked(event, x, y);
           }
       });

       root.add(name).row();
       root.add(emailId).row();
       root.add(signIn).width(150).height(50f).row();
       root.add(disconnect).width(150).height(50f);

       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

      public void updateData(String name,String emilId){
          this.name.setText("Name : "+name.toUpperCase());
          this.emailId.setText("Email : "+emilId.toUpperCase());
      }

      @Override
      public void render () {
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         stage.act();
         stage.draw();
      }

      @Override
      public void dispose () {
         stage.dispose();
         skin.dispose();
      }

      @Override
      public void resize(int width, int height) {
          stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
      }
   }
   ```

Inside ios module :

1. `IOSLauncher.java`

   ```
   public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate implements GIDSignInDelegate {

     private MyGDXTest main;

     @Override
     protected IOSApplication createApplication() {

       IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
       return  new IOSApplication(main=new MyGDXTest(new IOSSignIn(this)), config);
     }

     public static void main(String[] argv) {
         NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
         UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
         pool.close();
     } 

   @Override
   public boolean openURL(UIApplication app, NSURL url, UIApplicationOpenURLOptions options) {
       return GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().handleURL(url,options.getSourceApplication(),(NSPropertyList)options.getAnnotation());
   }


   @Override
   public void didSignIn(GIDSignIn signIn, GIDGoogleUser user, NSError error) {

       if (error==null){
           GIDProfileData gidProfileData=user.getProfile();
           main.updateData(gidProfileData.getName(),gidProfileData.getEmail());
       }

       Gdx.app.log("GIDSignInDelegate:didSignIn", "Error is "+error);
   }

     @Override
     public void didDisconnect(GIDSignIn signIn, GIDGoogleUser user, NSError error) {
         if (user==null) {
             main.updateData("", "");
         }
         Gdx.app.log("GIDSignInDelegate:didDisconnect", "Error is "+error);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `IOSSignIn`     // ios implementation class of SignInServiceApi

   ```
   public class IOSSignIn implements SignInServiceApi {

      private final static String CLIENT_ID = "1111-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

      public IOSSignIn(IOSLauncher app){

          GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setDelegate(app);

          GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setUiDelegate(new GIDSignInUIDelegateAdapter() {

             @Override
             public void willDispatch(GIDSignIn signIn, NSError error) { }

             @Override
             public void presentViewController(GIDSignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController) {
                UIViewController libgdxViewController =  UIApplication.getSharedApplication().getKeyWindow().getRootViewController();
               libgdxViewController.presentViewController(viewController, true, null);
             }

             @Override
             public void dismissViewController(GIDSignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController) {
               viewController.dismissViewController(true, null);
             }
       });
      }

      @Override
      public void signIn() {
          GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().setClientID(CLIENT_ID);
          GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().signIn();
      }

     @Override
     public void signOut() {
         GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().signOut();
         GIDSignIn.getSharedInstance().disconnect();
      }
   }
   ```

I've tested again with my another google account, working fine for me on my iPhone.

Comment: i followed your advice but nothing Ui shows in my emulator, my code here:
i change GIDSignInDelegate to GIDSignInDelegateAdapter because IOSLauncher$2 cannot be cast to org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject

Comment: I've tested yesterday on my iPhone(not tested on emulator), I'm able to login and getting UserData after login like email id and more, I can post my code later when i reach home.

Comment: @HồQuốcHuy I've updated my answer with my test code, I hope this may be helpful for you.

Comment: @quangkid, Updated my answer please check.

Comment: yeah i get error:Error is Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-2 "keychain error". so UI login not show to me. i have to turn on keychain

Comment: i add ‘4.0.0’ version of google SDK but get error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. Did you have a similar problem?. i add 2.4.0 so it run fine but sdk is deprecated. i using robovm version 2.3.3

Comment: i run it on real device.it work fine but emulator is nothing is showed.

Comment: i succeed. i forgot add library google sign in by hand in robovm.xml. thanks you for your help. you're generous

Comment: Great, you've caught your problem...Happy Coding :)